# Excel ListObject (Format as Table) in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oledb, listobject

You can use SQL in Excel VBA to query worksheets like this:

```vb
Dim relConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set relConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
relConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
    & ThisWorkbook.FullName _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open "SELECT [MyWorksheet$].MyFirstLineHeader FROM [MyWorksheet$]", relConn
While (Not rs.EOF)
  ...
Wend
```

→ Worksheets are referred to as `[WorksheetName$]` in SQL.

In SQL, how can I refer to a [ListObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) which is created by selecting a range and choosing [Format as Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-an-excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370) from the Home ribbon? In VBA they are accessed like this: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyWorksheet").ListObjects("MyTableName")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```vb
Dim s as string
s = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyWorksheet").ListObjects("MyTableName").Range.Address(0, 0)
rs.Open "SELECT [MyFirstLineHeader] FROM [MyWorkSheet$" & s & "]", relConn
```

Comment: This one works! I accepted it as an answer but if someone knows how to refer in SQL to the table's name,  I'll accept it. Thank you @CDP1802.